# Скрипт не работает вне IDE

Tags: python, ос, multiprocessing, pyautogui, python-keyboard

```
import random
import pyautogui as pg
from time import sleep
import os
import keyboard
import signal
import multiprocessing as mp

flag = True # Флаг состояния потока moveTo_pressF5_thread

# Функция для убийства приложения
def hook(pid):
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl + shift + alt + s'):
            os.kill(pid,signal.SIGTERM)
            os._exit(1)

# Функция для случайных движений мышкой и перезагрузки страницы
def moveTo_pressF5():
    global flag
    while flag:
        a, b, c = random.randint(500,1000), random.randint(300,600), random.randint(1, 5)
        sleep(10)
        pg.moveTo(a, b, c)
        sleep(40)
        pg.press('f5')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pid = os.getpid()
    exit_process = mp.Process(target=hook,args=[pid]) # завершение программы
    exit_process.start()

    pause = mp.Process(target=moveTo_pressF5) # процесс движения мышкой и обновления
    pause.start()


    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + shift + alt + p"):
            flag = False
            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') # очистка терминала от сообщений про скрипт
            print('Скрипт приостановлен, нажмите ctrl + alt + p для продолжения')
            pause.terminate()
            
            keyboard.wait('ctrl + alt + p')
            flag = True
            
            print("Скрипт продолжается...")

            pause = mp.Process(target=moveTo_pressF5) # процесс движения мышкой и нажатия ф5
            pause.start()
```

Как и написано в заголовке при запуске скрипта вне IDE (когда запускаешь через python) скрипт перестает нормально работать. Функционал паузы вроде бы работает, однако если в самом начале (спустя секунду, может две после запуска) нажать комбинацию закрытия скрипта (ctrl + shift + alt + s), то ничего не происходит. При этом сам скрипт вроде как не очень тяжелый, однако жрет 100% процессора.

Comment: Жрёт очевидно `while True`, а запускать всё в отдельных процессах и потом возиться с завершением этой кучи процессов это как-то странно

Comment: Я не представляю как без них обойтись: без `while True` в функции `hook` не получится закрыть скрипт, без `while True` в `moveTo_pressF5` не будет функционала, а без `while True` в `if __name__ == '__main__'` не будет паузы. До этого пытался переписать засунув функционал паузы в функцию `hook`, но оттуда потоки нельзя прекратить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте попробуем упростить:

```
import random
import pyautogui as pg
from time import sleep
import os
import keyboard
import threading
import multiprocessing

exit_Process = None # Тут будем хранить объект multiprocessing.Process

# Функция для убийства приложения
def hook_exit():
    keyboard.wait('ctrl + shift + alt + s')
    print("!!!")
    exit_Process.terminate() # Перед закрытием программы завершаем процесс moveTo_pressF5
    os._exit(1)

# Функция для случайных движений мышкой и перезагрузки страницы
def moveTo_pressF5():
    while True:
        a, b, c = random.randint(500,1000), random.randint(300,600), random.randint(1, 5)
        sleep(10)
        pg.moveTo(a, b, c)
        sleep(40)
        pg.press('f5')

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    # Создаем поток для выхода из программы по нажатию сочетания клавиш
    hook_exit_thread = threading.Thread(target=hook_exit)
    hook_exit_thread.start() # Запускаем поток
   
    while True:
        # Создаем Process для движении мыши и обновления страницы
        moveTo_pressF5_Process = multiprocessing.Process(target=moveTo_pressF5)
        exit_Process = moveTo_pressF5_Process
        moveTo_pressF5_Process.start() # Запускаем Process

        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print("Running... \n")
        
        print('Нажмите ctrl + shift + alt + p что бы поставить скрипт на паузу')
        keyboard.wait("ctrl + shift + alt + p")
        
        moveTo_pressF5_Process.terminate()
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

        print('Скрипт приостановлен, нажмите ctrl + alt + p для продолжения')  
        keyboard.wait('ctrl + alt + p')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает! Насчёт моего кода - я так понимаю он отказывался исполнять некоторые функции из-за нагрузки процессора или ещё чего-то?

Comment: Основной проблемой для вашей системы оказались циклы, возможно бы вопрос решил банальный `sleep(0.01)`, но я решил что лучше будет оптимизировать этот момент.